# Byte to signed int in C

Tags: c, casting, binary-data

I have a binary value stored in a char in C, I want transform this byte into signed int in C. 
Currently I have something like this:

```
char a = 0xff;
int b = a; 
printf("value of b: %d\n", b);
```

The result in standard output will be "255", the desired output is "-1".

Comment: Cast to `signed char` first:
`int b = (signed char) a;`

Comment: `ff` as hexadecimal is 255 so, if you want -1 what sort of conversion or transformation are you expecting?

Comment: Thank you guys oldrinb and Charles =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace:

```
char a = 0xff
```

by

```
signed char a = 0xff;  // or more explicit: = -1
```

to have `printf` prints `-1`.

If you don't want to change the type of `a`, as @veer added in the comments you can simply cast `a` to `(signed char)` before assigning its value to `b`.

Note that in both cases, this integer conversion is implementation-defined but this is the commonly seen implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: `signed char a = 0xff` is an overflow on if `char` is 8 bit wide. So just don't do that. Your second guess of `-1` is more convincing :)

Comment: @JensGustedt this is not an overflow in the sense of the C definition. This is perfectly valid (but implementation-defined) C code.

Comment: @JensGustedt no it isn't an overflow here.

Comment: Hm, `signed char` usually can hold values from `-128` to `127`. Here you are assigning the unsigned value `255` to it. This is an overflow.  Ouah is right that what happens then is implementation defined. Among these implementation defined things that can happen is "raising a signal".

Comment: @JensGustedt the `255` value is converted before the assignment to `(signed char)` and this conversion is ruled by 6.3.1.3p3 in C99. No overflow occurs because the conversion happens before

Comment: @ouah, ok let's call this an out-of-range error, if you prefer. Still the system is allowed to crash the program under you.

Comment: @JensGustedt But it must say that in the documentation, if it does.

Comment: @DanielFischer, sure. If you want to write portable code, you better document clearly that your code is going to crash under that assumption. I think it is just easier to avoid such cruft. If you want to see it as signed quantity declare it as such and assign `-1` it is as simple as that.

Comment: @DanielFischer By the way C says that *(C99, 4.p3) A program that is correct in all other aspects, operating on correct data, containing
unspecified behavior shall be a correct program* and by definition implementation-defined behavior is an unspecified behavior. I don't think crashing is a OK behavior for a correct program.

Comment: But the standard explicitly mentions the possibility of raising an implementation-defined signal when converting to signed integer types and the value isn't representable in the target type. I'd say in this case, crashing is allowed, as long as the implementation documents it.

Answer (score 5):

According to the C99 standard,

> **6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**
>
> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than **_Bool**, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>
> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type.
>
> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
>   result is implementation-deﬁned or an implementation-deﬁned signal is raised.

---

You need to cast your `char` to a `signed char` before assigning to `int`, as any value `char` could take is directly representable as an `int`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char a = 0xff;
  int b = (signed char) a;
  printf("value of b: %d\n", b);
  return 0;
}
```

---

Quickly testing shows it works here:

```
C:\dev\scrap>gcc -std=c99 -oprint-b print-b.c

C:\dev\scrap>print-b
value of b: -1
```

---

Be wary that `char` is undefined by the C99 standard as to whether it is treated signed or unsigned.

> **6.2.5 Types**
>
> An object declared as type **char** is large enough to store any member of the basic
>   execution character set. If a member of the basic execution character set is stored in a
>   **char** object, its value is guaranteed to be positive. If any other character is stored in a **char** object, the resulting value is implementation-deﬁned but shall be within the range of values that can be represented in that type.
>
> ...
>
> The three types **char**, **signed char**, and **unsigned char** are collectively called
>   the character types. The implementation shall define char to have the same range,
>   representation, and behavior as either **signed char** or **unsigned char**.

Comment: It should be noted that, technically, signed integer overflow causes undefined behavior, so in order to get consistent results from platform to platform, you'd need to define the wrap-around semantics yourself (i.e. check for SCHAR_MAX and act accordingly)

Comment: Could a fictive compiler legally have (say) `SCHAR_MAY == 512`, such that this code would print "value of b: 255"?

Comment: @eq this is not an overflow in C here but an integer conversion ruled by 6.3.1.3p3 in C99. So no undefined behavior here.

Comment: @ouah, just to cite it directly: *"either the
result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised"*, so right no undefined behavior, but it might just crash the program under you :)

Answer (score 1):

You are already wrong from the start:

```
char a = 0xff;
```

if `char` is `signed`, which you seem to assume, here you already have a value that is out of range, `0xFF` is an unsigned quantity with value `255`. If you want to see `char` as signed numbers use `signed char` and assign `-1` to it. If you want to see it as a bit pattern use `unsigned char` and assign `0xFF` to it. Your initialization of the `int` will then do what you expect it to do.

`char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are by definition of the standard three different types. Reserve `char` itself to characters, printing human readable stuff.

Comment: Note that by definition they are three distinct types but actually `char` is either `unsigned char` or `signed char`. DR #068 clarifies that http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_068.html

Comment: @ouah, to be even more clear on that: `char` has the same range of values as one of the `[un]signed char` types, but it is a distinct type (as seen in C's type system) from any of those. The point that I wanted to make is that there are *semantic* differences between these three types as they are given by the standard, and you should use them for what they are *meant*. Don't use `char` for arithmetic if you can avoid it, you easily get it wrong on the other half of the possible platforms.